# voltage level handled using optocoupler

Tags: embedded, opto-isolator, flash, logic-level, programmer

I want to program at89c2051 chip. I am referring circuit diagram where the optocoupler is used to handle the 2 voltage levels (+12V and +5V).
i didn't understand how Pin A0 and A1 will control the voltage level. Here is the optocoupler circuit
[image]

Comment: Where did you get this circuit from?

Comment: check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396577/help-understanding-this-schematic-why-is-the-diode-there-at89c2051-programmer

Comment: yes. So the design is not perfect. With this design controller pins may get damaged. I am thinking of using PNP transistors to control the voltages level.

Comment: @dev_eng Not exactly, the diode is intentionally added to avoid damaging A0 pin (reread the answer in the mentioned link). by using this circuit you can safely follow the programming algorithm described in the datasheet of at89c2051.